# SMTP response code for duplicate Message-ID value

Tags: smtp

What SMTP response code should the server send to report that the `Message-ID` field duplicates one already seen?

[RFC 5322, §3.6.4 “Identification Fields”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) states:

> The "Message-ID:" field provides a unique message identifier that
> refers to a particular version of a particular message. The
> uniqueness of the message identifier is guaranteed by the host that
> generates it […].

So it is a violation of that directive for a message to declare a Message-ID value that has already been seen on a message with different content. This implies that an SMTP server may reject a message on that basis.

Note: The intent is not to remember *every* value *ever seen*; that would be onerous to design and expensive to operate. Rather, the intent is to use *those values we happen to record* to detect some proportion of incoming requests that violate the above directive, and reject them early on that basis.

The set of codes described in [RFC 5321 §4.2 “SMTP replies”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2) describes some conditions where fields are the cause of a rejection (e.g. “mailbox not allowed”, reply code 553).

What should be the response code for the condition “Message-ID value already seen”?

Comment: Beware false positives from buggy_thing_x_that_you_must_integrate_with...

Comment: You don't reject such mail. You accept it for delivery.

Comment: The rest of the description of message ID in section 3.6.4 implies that **you cannot reject mail with duplicate message IDs**. Automata have no way of knowing why the message is being resent with the same ID. The only safe thing to do is to deliver it. This is not a difficult concept.

Answer (score 1):

The MTA agent **can not and must not** reject a mail for delivery based on its Message-ID.

Doing that would require the MTA to know (and remember) *all* the system-wide used Message-ID, which obviously is prohibitive both on CPU, memory and disk requirements.

In short, the MTA *must accept* mails with duplicate Message-ID, leaving the (optional) subsequent de-deplication work for later processing (eg: by the IMAP server or mail client).

Comment: “Doing that would require the MTA to know (and remember) all the system-wide used Message-ID, which obviously is prohibitive both on CPU, memory and disk requirements.” — That's not an implication of this question. I've updated the description to clarify.

Comment: @bignose If you already rejected a message for some other reason, and it shows up again, you'll just reject it for the same other reason. Keeping track of message IDs is unnecessary and pointless.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, if an already-used Message-ID shows up again on a different message (as described in RFC 5322), that's violating the directive in §3.6.4. That's the justification for rejecting it when the request is incoming.

Comment: @bignose Maybe, but you're still wasting your time trying to keep track of every message-ID you've ever seen.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I've clarified in the question description that “keep track of every message-ID you've ever seen” is not an implication of this question.

Comment: @bignose I read your "clarification" but it really doesn't say much of anything and your comment immediately above it seems to contradict it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55564/discussion-between-bignose-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: @shodanshok I'm curious about 'must not' -- I understand it is prohibitive to block based on this universally, but why 'must not' it happen -- if someone wants to spend the resources to do it, why not?

Comment: Because buggy client/mtas can sometime reuse the same message-id for different emails. Moreover, in no SMTP RFCs I can see a SHOULD/MUST DROP (or similar), so the MTA should not do that.